# Правильно ли выражение «проигнорировав двумя вещами»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно: *проигнорировав **двумя вещами*** или *проигнорировав **две вещи***?

Comment: Да, первый вариант подошёл бы к "пожонглировав двумя вещами" (хотя лучше "предметами"). :)))

Answer (score 2):

[игнорировать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) [от лат. *ignorare* — не знать], **кого-что.** [винительный падеж]
Умышленно не заметить — не замечать, намеренно не обратить — не обращать внимание на что-либо. *Игнорировать окружающих. Игнорировать чьи-либо доводы. Полностью, абсолютно игнорировать кого-либо, что-либо.*

Правильно: проигнорировав (кого?) меня; **проигнорировав** (что?) **две вещи.**

*...положила пластиковый лист с прогнозируемыми результатами на видное место на случай появления Гайяра и, выключив систему и **проигнорировав два пищевых бокса** — усталость подавляла даже аппетит, — побрела в спальню* (А. Медведева).

Тут дело такое. Думаю, что путаница в употреблении падежей происходит из-за синонимичного глагола [пренебречь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C) (пренебрегать), который требует творительного падежа [**кем-чем** / (устар.) кого-что]: **пренебречь двумя вещами.**

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так: проигнорировав <del>(чем?)</del> (что?) **две вещи**.

Comment: Что означает, простите, это изобразительное искусство?

Comment: То, что вопрос "чем?", а соответственно, и "двумя вещами" не верно. Это же очевидно.

Comment: А читающий (в том числе иностранцы) должны догадываться, что вам лень   было написать это словами? Ну как скажете...

Answer (score 0):

Игнорировать (что? - винтельный падеж) - **две вещи**. И только так.
**Двумя вещами** (чем? - падеж творительный) можно, например, пренебречь.
Смешение управление тут недопустимо.